# Conditional Mapping of Array Reactjs - Jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to map Select Menu Options using an array, if array contains **"mobile"** substring in it, it should render option as **Selected** else it will render as normal.

But that's not working:

```
<select>
    {xarray.map((heading, index) => 
        {heading.headingis.toLowerCase().indexOf('mobile') != -1 ?
            <option value="{heading.headingis}" key={index} selected>{heading.headingis}</option>
            :
            <option value="{heading.headingis}" key={index}>{heading.headingis}</option>
        }
    )}  
</select>
```

It is rendering empty dropdown menu. Is there anything wrong or other way of doing this?

Without condition it is working fine.

P.S. **headingis** is sub index of array. which may contain Mobile Number, Name etc.

Comment: return statement missing in map method.

Comment: Thanks, `{return heading.headingis.toLowerCase().indexOf('mobile') != -1 ?` Worked.